# Position: absolute, избегание positon:relative родителя

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Нужно сделать так чтобы блок с классом `.child` мог выходить за рамки родителя, При это не убирая у родителя css код `position: relative` (это важно).

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  }
  
  .child {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Не очень понятно, что подразумеваете под *мог выходить за рамки родителя*.

Могу предположить, что можно просто использовть отрицательные значения `left` и `top`.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

маргином можно двигать )

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  }
  
  .child {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: -50%
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Только если child вынести за parent. Нельзя наложить **absolute** на **relative**, если **absolute** находится в **relative**. Даже `z-index` не поможет

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.block {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.block-1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #3a78a1;
}

.block-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.block-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="block block-1">Блок 1</div>
  <div class="block block-2">Блок 2</div>
  <div class="block block-3">Блок 3</div>
</body>
```